# Manually send cookie to client for express sessions

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express-session

Here is my basic set up.

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cors = require('cors'),
helmet = require('helmet'),
rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit'),
enrouten = require('express-enrouten'),
session = require('express-session'),
uuid = require('uuid/v4'),
fileStore = require('session-file-store')(session),
passport = require('passport');

//Start express
var app = express();

//Set global variables
global.config = require('./config/config');

//Set up express middleware
app.use([
  //Body Parser middleware
  bodyParser.json(),
  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),

  //Disable cors
  cors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,POST',
    preflightContinue: false,
    credentials: false
  }),

  //Helmet middleware
  helmet({
    framegaurd: {
        action: 'deny'
    },
    hsts: {
        maxAge: 5184000,
        includeSubDomains: true,
        preload: true
    },
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com']
        }
    }
  }),

  //Express rate limit middleware
  rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
  }),

  //Session
  session({
    genid: function(req) {
        return uuid();
    },
    store: new fileStore(),
    secret: config.ss,
    resave: false,
    name: 'website',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        domain: '.website.com',
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
        maxAge: 3600000
    },
    path: 'sessions'
  }),

  //Passport
  passport.initialize(),
  passport.session(),

  //Routes
  enrouten({
    directory: 'routes',
    index: 'routes/posts.js'
  })
]);

//Listen
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function() {
 console.log('Run');
});
```

I use passport and bcryptjs to authenticate a user https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/

Once the user has been authenticated, I can see the session is created in the session folder. However, I do not see a cookie with the corresponding session ID being created. I am curious if I either have registered my middleware in the wrong order or if I need to manually send the cookie to the front end?

I have read that cookieParser ships with express-sessions.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT- April 4, 2019**
I neglected to mention that my request is coming from a different subdomain than the server(shown above). The server is on api.website.com while the request is coming from new.website.com. Eventually, new.website.com will be website.com once i have fixed "all" the bugs

[image]

Comment: Try `cookie.key` instead `cookie.name`

Comment: are you saying to add key to the cookie object in the middleware? There is no cookie.name in the setup

Comment: sorry instead `name: 'website',` use `key: 'website',`

Comment: nope - i got the same result which is nothing - i can see the data being return because it is updating values in my store(vuex) but when i click the security button i do not see the cookie. likewise, i can see the session being created just not set on the client - i have used .webste.com to set up a wildcard for subdomains

Comment: You check is server set cookies in headers? (in "firebug", network tab)

Comment: i do not see any cookie in the headers

Comment: The Node server does not show any errors that the cookie can not be set?

Comment: im using plesk which uses phusion passanger and nginx. i have looked at the log files and i cannot see any errors

Comment: if i set it up using the localhost i still dont see any errors